# Not sure if ROW_NUMBER will work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns in AccountId, AgreementId.

[image]

I want another column where the first two rows would return 1 as 5552 is the first AccountId against the same AgreementId....
The next rows would all return 2 as it;s the second rent account it can find.

Any idea how I would do that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dense_rank()`:

```
select *,
       dense_rank() over (order by AccountId, AgreementId) Seq
from table t;
```

Comment: @ikilledbill If this helped you to solve your issue it would be kind to vote on all helpful contributions and to accept the one answer you think is best. This is sometimes hard to decide... You might take "who was the first?" into account. Sometimes you'd choose the aswer with the better explanation. This is up to you. This pays reputation points to those who spent their time helping you and to your own accout. This is the SO way to say *Thanks*. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `DENSE_RANK` here:

```
SELECT
    AccountId,
    AgreementId,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY AgreementId ORDER BY AccountId) dr
FROM yourTable;
```

The partition by agreement means that the numbering would reset for each separate agreement.  Within an agreement, we use the account ID to order the dense rank.